# What is the word for putting an image in someone's head by describing it?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm not quite sure how to put this but I'm writing an essay on *To Kill a Mockingbird* and Tom Robinson, the defendant in the court trial within the novel, describes what actually happened during the time that Mayella, the plaintiff, is accusing him of rape.

I need a word for how Tom Robinson "imagerizes" the incident.

One word preferred.

Comment: In some cases it might be "painting a picture".

Comment: What's the problem with *describes*? Although I do like imagerizes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Vivid" means clear and detailed, easily distinguished.  As an adverb, "Vividly" means to do something in a manner as to produce such a clear and detailed picture in someone's head.

So the term you want is "vividly describes".

Answer (score 0):

**Evokes**

Evokes means to cause a response in somebody. One could evoke a feeling, a memory, a mood or a response (of any kind) from another.

Examples:

- The scent of roses evokes the memory of my grandmother
- The smell of home cooking evoked memories of home in me
- As he smelled smoke, he felt afraid, remembering the childhood disaster (that it evoked)
- Tom told an evocative story that made the jury feel that they had followed along with him on his blackberry-picking journey on that fateful afternoon

It means that the person feels like they are ‘back in the situation’ as if it is happening now.

https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/evoke